# Typescript inference issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a generic Store using React's useReducer and useContext but I'm having an issue with the inference of the default state.

The store generator function is the following:

```js
export function generateStore<Actions extends ReducerAction, State = any>(defaultValue: State, reducer: (state: State, action: Actions) => State): {
  provider: (props: { children: ReactNode }) => ReactElement;
  dispatcher: (action: Actions) => void;
  useStore: () => State;
} {
  const store = createContext(defaultValue);
  const { Provider } = store;

  let dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>;

  const ProviderElm = (props: { children: ReactNode }): ReactElement => {
    const { children } = props;
    const [state, dispatcher] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);
    dispatch = dispatcher;
    return <Provider value={state}>{children}</Provider>;
  };

  return {
    provider: ProviderElm,
    dispatcher: (action: Actions) => dispatch && dispatch(action),
    useStore: () => useContext(store),
  };
}
```

An initializer example could be:

```js
const defaultState = {
  auth: {
    authenticated: false,
  },
};

type StoreActions =
  | {
      type: 'LOGIN';
      payload: {
        token: string;
      };
    }
  | {
      type: 'LOGOUT';
    };

const { dispatcher, provider, useStore } = generateStore<StoreActions>(
  defaultState,
  (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN': {
        const { token } = action.payload;
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: true,
            token,
          },
        };
      }
      case 'LOGOUT': {
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: false,
            token: null,
          },
        };
      }

      default:
        return defaultState;
    }
  },
);
```

The issue is that the `State` generic of `generateStore` can't infer itself as the typeof the parameter `defaultValue`.

It always requires me to initialize it like this or else the intellisense won't work out the type:
`generateStore<StoreActions, typeof defaultState>`

Any idea on how I make this work and why it currently can't infer the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to infer your generic types. You cannot provide any type arguments to the function. TypeScript does not support partial type inference. It's all or nothing. By calling `generateStore<StoreActions>` you are triggering the compiler to use the predefined `State = any` generic argument on your function.

I would recommend having a strongly typed state to make it cleaner.

```
type State = {
  auth: {
    authenticated: boolean
  }
}

type StoreActions =
  | {
    type: 'LOGIN';
    payload: {
      token: string;
    };
  }
  | {
    type: 'LOGOUT';
  };

const defaultState: State = {
  auth: {
    authenticated: false,
  },
};

const { dispatcher, provider, useStore } = generateStore<StoreActions, State>(
  defaultState,
  (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN': {
        const { token } = action.payload;
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: true,
            token,
          },
        };
      }
      case 'LOGOUT': {
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: false,
            token: null,
          },
        };
      }

      default:
        return defaultState;
    }
  },
);
```

The only other option is to create a wrapper function that only needs one argument to infer (the state) and supplies the actions type directly. You'll need one for each set of actions, but it might be a good work around depending on how many times it will be used.

```
type StoreActions =
  | {
    type: 'LOGIN';
    payload: {
      token: string;
    };
  }
  | {
    type: 'LOGOUT';
  };

const defaultState = {
  auth: {
    authenticated: false,
  },
};

export function generateStoreWithStoreActions<State = any>(defaultValue: State, reducer: (state: State, action: StoreActions) => State) {
  return generateStore<StoreActions, State>(defaultValue, reducer);
}

const { dispatcher, provider, useStore } = generateStoreWithStoreActions(
  defaultState,
  (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN': {
        const { token } = action.payload;
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: true,
            token,
          },
        };
      }
      case 'LOGOUT': {
        return {
          ...state,
          auth: {
            authenticated: false,
            token: null,
          },
        };
      }

      default:
        return defaultState;
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Perfect explanation. Shame tho. Either way I still have a workaround. Thank you